# Mass fraction of fuel on a fuel droplet surface

Tags: thermodynamics

Concerning combustion of fuel droplets:

Why is the mass fraction of fuel on a fuel droplet surface slightly less than one?

It is known that the temperature is below the boiling point at the fuel droplet surface, so there is no evaporation at the surface and therefore my intuition tell me that the mass fraction of the fuel at the surface should be unity, but it isn't. So why is the mass fraction of fuel less than one, and what happened to that fraction of fuel mass?

Answer (score 1):

At the liquid surface, the vapor phase exists as a mixture of fuel vapor ($m_f$ - which is a function of surface temperature, $T_s$) and air ($m_a$). As a result the mass-fraction of fuel vapor ($Y_{f,s}$) at the fuel surface will be less than unity. Depending on the volatility of the fuel and the ambient conditions, the value of $Y_{f,s}$ will vary from a value slightly below unity to zero (especially when the ambient temperature too low compared to the normal boiling point of the fuel).